# how to keep a large number of data.frame in .csv

Tags: r

There are a large number of data.frame (more than 50). How can I save them quickly in .csv?

```
write.csv()
```

50 lines of code, it's awful...

Help me, guys!

Comment: Do you want to save them into one CSV or into separate files. If the former, can you combine them into one data.frame?

Comment: [Put them in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/4497050) and use `lapply`.

Comment: data.frame each in separate .csv file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a list of data frames?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the many data.frames may be available in in your R session...

First create a vector with the **names** of the data.frames... use `ls` or some thing similar. Then use `get` to get the R object after the names (the data.frames in this case)

```
myfiles <- ls ()
```

Then

```
for (d in myfiles) {
    current <- get (d)
    write.csv (current, filename = paste0 (d, ".csv"))
}
```